# Вывод URL-изображения в Андроид

Tags: android, java

Всем доброго времени суток. Долгое время бьюсь над проблемой: нужно вывести изображение во imageView через SimpleAdapter по внешним ссылкам. Данные получаю в формате JSON.
Нашел интересную вещь — Android Universal Image Loader, и прикрутить не получается, точнее написать адаптер для моего случая.

Как решить подобную задачу? Хотелось бы видеть примеры.

**P.S**: c.getString(TAG_IMAGE) — содержит полный путь до изображения.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Создаем JSON парсер
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> testsList;

// url получения списка всех тестов
private static String url_tests = "http://192.168.0.4/api/v1/tests";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_STATUS = "status";
private static final String TAG_DATA = "data";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
private static final String TAG_IMAGE = "image";

// тут будет хранится список тестов
JSONArray tests = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    testsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

    // Загружаем тесты в фоновом потоке
    new LoadAllTests().execute();

    // получаем ListView
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // на выбор одного теста
    // запускается Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String tid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Запускаем новый intent который покажет нам Activity
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            // отправляем id в следующий activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_ID, tid);

            // запуская новый Activity ожидаем ответ обратно
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

}

/**
 * Фоновый Async Task для загрузки всех продуктов по HTTP запросу
 * */
class LoadAllTests extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Перед началом фонового потока Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Загрузка...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Получаем все продукт из url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Будет хранить параметры
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // получаем JSON строк с URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_tests, "GET", params);

        Log.d("All Tests: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Получаем SUCCESS тег для проверки статуса ответа сервера
            String status = json.getString(TAG_STATUS);

            if (status.equals("OK")) {
                // тест найден
                // Получаем масив из Тестов
                tests = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);

                // перебор всех продуктов
                for (int i = 0; i < tests.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = tests.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Сохраняем каждый json елемент в переменную
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                    String image = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);

                    Log.v(TAG_STATUS, "c.getString(TAG_IMAGE) = "+c.getString(TAG_IMAGE));
                    Log.v(TAG_STATUS, "image = "+image);

                    // Создаем новый HashMap
                    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                    // добавляем каждый елемент в HashMap ключ => значение
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_TITLE, name);
                    map.put(TAG_IMAGE, image);

                    // добавляем HashList в ArrayList
                    testsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * После завершения фоновой задачи закрываем прогрес диалог
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // закрываем прогресс диалог после получение всех тестов
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // обновляем UI форму в фоновом потоке
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Обновляем распарсенные JSON данные в ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        MainActivity.this, testsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_ID, TAG_TITLE, TAG_IMAGE},
                        new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.title, R.id.url_image });
                // обновляем listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для подобных задач рекомендую связку gson + retrofit + picasso:

- [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) ─ для реализации rest api, работая в связке с gson, серализует ответ;
- [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) ─ для удобной работы вам придется описать модели, если забыть про картинку, то можно просто перегрузить toString и юзать обычный адаптер;
- [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) ─ альтернатива Universal Image Loader, имеет ряд преимуществ, и на мой взгляд, более удобен в использовании, так же, как и retrofit, творение всеми любимого square.

Comment: А случайно примера не найдется? Спасибо.

Comment: Еще для изображений есть https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 0):

Буквально на днях столнулся с тойже проблемой! Мне нужно было данные из JSON поместить в ListView, в том числе и картинку. После долгих поисков нашел небольшую серию видеоуроков на эту тему. Уроки буржуйские (не пойму, какой язык), но по действиям все понятно. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Lr37suTPpg&list=PLsoBxH455yoZZeeza9TiG8I9dGP0zz5o9&index=1

Comment: Попробовал. Но код работает плохо — загрузка изображений происходит при скроллинге постоянно, и происходит какой-то постоянный перебор изображений при скролле.

Comment: У меня все работает хорошо! Но другой способ попробую тоже...